# Beginners Tutorial for Zend Framework implementing model and call it from Controller

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, model

I'm quite new to ZF, and right now, i try to write a tiny app, based on ZF. It works more or less fine until now. I wanna access my db- data. For starters, i just want to use query-string, before I start messing araound with zend_db. So to keep a nice mvc-structure, I created application/models/IndexMapper.php

```
class Application_Models_IndexMapper{...}
```

it just contains one function by now to see if it works

```
 public function test(){
    return ('yay');
}
```

In my IndexController, which is working, i try to access my model by

```
$indexMapper = new Application_Models_IndexMapper();
$x = $indexMapper->test();
```

but the first line throws an

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application_Models_IndexMapper' not found in /path/to/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 31
```

As I'm new, I don't understand the more complex tutorials and they don't help me fix my problem. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to include it somehow?

Thanks

edit: my application/bootstrap.php

```
<?php

defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    or define('APPLICATION_PATH' , dirname(__FILE__));


defined('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT')
    or define('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT' , 'development');


require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();


$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

$frontController->setControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers');

$frontController->setParam('env', APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT);

Zend_Layout::startMvc(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/scripts');


//Doctype
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
$view->doctype('HTML5');

$view->addHelperPath('App/View/Helper', 'App_View_Helper');


unset($frontController);
```

Comment: That looks more like index.php than bootstrap.php.

Comment: Your best bet is to start over, for the size if application you're working on your bootstrap should be empty (or almost). Use Zend_Tool CLI to setup the project and you'll find most of this in your index.php and your application.ini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess my tutorial wasn't very helpful. I'll do as recommended, and start over from scratch. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

The structure for a model would be found under `./application/models/IndexMapper.php`. In that file you would have the class As you named it and then the autoloading will work.

A great beginner tutorial would be found on www.akrabat.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had the file in the right place and named it like that too. I'll check out the website too in detail, but i already have the book he wrote, and it also uses zend_db to introduce the modellayer, whihc isn't helpfull for my as I 'd like to understand first, how to include the model :/

Answer (score 0):

You have your class in the wrong place and have named it incorrectly.

Your class should be in `application/models/Indexmapper.php` and should look like this:-

```
class Application_Model_Indexmapper
{
    public function test(){
        return ('yay');
    }
}
```

Then you call it thus:-

```
$indexMapper = new Application_Model_Indexmapper();
$x = $indexMapper->test();
```

Notice I dropped the 's' from the end of Models, it is not required and will cause an error as you found. Also the class is in the models folder, not modules. If you want to use modules then you need to read [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/project-structure.filesystem.html) and [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.modular.html) from the manual.

Your bootstrap.php should look like this for a first, basic project:-

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    //Yes, it's empty!
}
```

Comment: @vascowhile Thanks for your reply. I had my class in the right place, and i tried before withoud the s in models, but i still get the same error. I removed the uppercase m, still the same error. I'll post my bootstrap in my question. maybe my mistake is already done there (I#ve git it from a tut though..) would you mind checking it?

Comment: @Nareille `models` not `modules`: check your directory name.

Comment: @vascowhile sorry, i corrected it in my question. it was correct in my project though. sorry for the mix up

Comment: @vascowhile :( if i empty it, i get a bunch of errors.. my current setup is from a tutorial as i said, already implementing an Errorcontroller and stuff. let's assume, there won't be an autoloader, how would i have to load the directory for the models folder? I think my app just can't find the folder/doesn't know it's supposed to include it

Comment: @Nareille Go back to the default installation of ZF with the standard index.php and standard bootstrap.php. Have you followed the [quickstart guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.html)? Can you link the tutorial you have followed?

Comment: i did the videos from zendcasts.com

Comment: a lot of those videos are old and out of date. Newer version of ZF change a lot in how an application is setup.